# Combining power

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-measurement

On a computer power supply can I add 12 volts and 5 volts supply to get 17 volt supply? **Edited for clarification

Comment: Sorry the comments weren't relative to the questions I left them out I'm just wanting to know if I can add two different + volts together and get a higher voltage? ie 12 and 5 to get 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. Not if the 5V rail that you intend to use is the one available on the same PSU.

The reason for this is that every supply rail in that PSU (+12, -12, +5, -5, +3.3, etc) shares a common reference ground. If you attempt to stack the 5V on top of the 12V, you will instead short 12V directly to the common ground of the PSU.

If, however, you use an entirely isolated power supply, then you can stack the voltages. But they must have isolated ground references.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get something out of nothing! You only read 24V because you are using the -12V as the "ground" reference for your measurement device. If you actually put the measurement device's "negative" pin on the board's "ground" point, you would get the correct readings of + or - 12V.

You don't really "add" a 5V rail on top of the 12V rail, and then read from -12 to give a nice fat +29V reference. Circuits do not normally work that way, but they WOULD if -12 was the "Ground".

I think you need to do some serious reading about what voltage and current are, and some simple circuit analysis - from the core laws of electrical circuits such as Ohms law, and two of Kirchoff's laws.

You can take an input voltage and convert it using various methods, using transformers, charge pump capacitors, and all sorts of awesome DC-DC conversion circuits. You cannot just 'add' a 5V rail to a +12V rail though.

For example Charge pumps take two separate capacitors and charge them up to a certain voltage, and then switch them together to give double voltage output, and do this very fast to give a stable higher voltage output.

You can get batteries which act are basically a source of voltage, and connect them in series and stack up their voltages, for example 2 x 12V batteries properly connected will give you 24V.

Negative voltages are generated with reference to ground, and they are 'sources' usually, not 'sinks' so you cannot really use them as a ground reference. I guess they could shunt spare power into the real ground, one way or another, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I am making a variable power supply from a pc power supply so that's the reason for the -12 reading as ground. But do so will it allow to add volts to get a higher voltage reading?

Comment: You seem to entirely miss the real issue in favor of a spurious one - most meters (with the exception of line powered or special purpose units) don't have a "ground" lead as they are isolated instruments which measure a potential *difference* between their leads.

Comment: @ChrisStratton indeed, however he misused the equipment. He fails to understand the point of voltage supplies, and their use.

Comment: @KyranF yes I'm after the adjustable power supply.

Comment: @DanielKimbril you should investigate buck-boost converters, you can buy ready made ones from eBay and other places which are "low power" (about 15 Watts, using the power equation you can work out the current for whatever voltage they can put out). Otherwise if you go from a larger supply such as a 24V or 30V supply, you can make/buy a Buck converter (step down voltage converter) which is adjustable, and again you can make a variable supply out of this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am new but allow me to describe the project. A regulated power supply using a pc power supply. I am using -12 volt rail as a ground and the +12 volt as the positive. I am also using a Lm 350T to adjust the output between 3.5 volts to 23 volts because the LM350T has a dropout voltage of 2 volts 3 if you count resistors used to create the setup. I also have an LED voltage reader used to set the voltage to the appropriate levels without using a meter every time. I added 2 10 watt/10 Ohm resistor to give the pwr supply a load.

Comment: @KyranF see my above comment

Comment: "No, voltage is with reference to "ground" - which is the return path of pretty much every circuit - ever." This is an **extremely mistaken assumption**.  Ground is a possible reference, but quite often **not the return**.  Much of the error in this answer follows from that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I shall adjust it. Actually I could not edit it anymore, so I deleted it. i'm sure he gets the jist of it now and his initial mistakes

Comment: @ChrisStratton can I point out that for most people, ground IS the return? I'm sure there is plenty of awesome theory and fancy circuits where ground is not the "return" but for most users it is

Comment: @KyranF - no, because the scope of cases where it is **not true** is fully comparable to those where it is.  Basically, it's true in simple, "negative ground" DC circuits and some signaling schemes, but not true in bipolar supply systems, single or multi-phase AC, etc - many of which are *extremely* common.

Comment: @ChrisStratton touche, I confess my knowledge and experience does not venture into any of those areas :(

Comment: @ChrisStratton so if I were trying to use this device only to give a breadboard power so I don't use a lot of batteries so I can learn to make circuits I can't use -12 as my ground?

Comment: You can use anything you want as your ground, as long as everything that is connected to "ground" agrees with your choice.  So, for example, if you use a desktop PC power supply with a 3 wire AC lead, and declare its -12v line to be the "ground" of your circuit, that is fine, but **do not connect the "ground" lead of a line-powered oscilloscope to it**.  Contrastingly, if you have a 2-wire cord laptop supply, or a battery powered scope, that particular issue is avoided.  There also exist **isolation transformers**, but floating line powered equipment can get you into safety-hazard territory.

Comment: can the -12V output rail absorb/take current? It might have a diode or FET blocking component which means it cannot source back to ground.. you could try? Honestly I think he's better off just getting some proper DC-DC conversion happening than playing with rails of a powerful desktop PC supply..

Comment: "can the -12V output rail absorb/take current? It might have a diode or FET blocking component which means it cannot source back to ground.." **it can't tell** if the path is completed through ground or through the positive rail. You are confusing the *different* case of connecting a distinct -12.5v source to the -12v rail - some supply designs can absorb a reasonable amount of such current, and some can't.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know that supplies can absorb current, because that is how clamping diodes for inductive loads like motors can recirculate current during switching, and voltage spikes above the rail, push current back into the supply etc..

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am using the -12 as my ground for all circuits designed on my breadboard. The ground from the pc power supply will not be available for use.

Comment: Yes - but the ground from the PC power supply probably will connect to your building wiring.  So you need to remember that the ground on your breadboard *is not* the same as the building wiring ground, and that *is likely to cause problems* if you connect any line-powered equipment to the breadboard at some point in the future without taking that into account.

Comment: So if I build a device that requires 9 volts and it's built using this power supply if I plug into a wall outlet it might be essentially built for 4.5 volts? Keep in mind I'm designing only DC devices

Comment: No, but if you connect something like the ground lead of a line-powered scope to the breadboard, you'd short out the negative half of the power supply - hopefully leading to a tripped protection or blown fuse, but possibly worse.